# Font changes when using Font Awesome icon

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'd like to use the icons beside a text, but every time I try to use an icon from Font Awesome, it changes the font style of the text. What should I do in order for the font to stay the same even if I include a Font Awesome icon into it? Here's my code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  var navOffset = jQuery(".nav").offset().top;

  jQuery(".nav").wrap('<div class="nav-placeholder"></div>');
  jQuery(".nav-placeholder").height(jQuery(".nav").outerHeight());

  jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

    var scrollPos = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

    if (scrollPos >= navOffset) {
      jQuery(".nav").addClass("fixed");
    } else {
      jQuery(".nav").removeClass("fixed");
    }

  });

});
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  margin: 0px;
}
.parallax {
  background-image: url('images/bg.jpg');
  height: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.parallax1 {
  background-image: url('images/bg.jpg');
  height: 46%;
  font-size: 0;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
ul.header {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #0d0d0d;
}
.nav {
  z-index: 999;
}
.navlink {
  display: inline-block
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #222422;
}
.nav-placeholder {
  margin: 0 0 0x 0;
}
.navlink a {
  font-family: arial;
  display: block;
  color: #f3f3f3;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15pt;
}
.navlink a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: #0d0d0d;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
.caption {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
}
.caption span.border {
  background-color: #111;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 18px;
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
}
.img1 {
  margin-top: 90px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
.img1:hover {
  transform: scale(0.9);
  cursor: pointer;
}
#products {
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 40pt;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parallax"></div>

<div class="caption">
  <span class="border"> WELCOME </span>
</div>

<div class="nav">
  <ul class="header">
    <ul class="header-content">
      <li class="navlink"><a href="{{ route('beverage_main') }}"><i class="fa fa-home w3-xxlarge"> Home</i></a></li>
      <li class="navlink"><a href="{{ route('beverage_foods') }}"> Foods </a></li>
      <li class="navlink"><a href="#"> Beverages </a></li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>

<div style="height:auto;background-color:#f2f2f2;font-size:36px;text-align:center;">
  <img class="img1" src="images/sw.jpg" width="350px" height="607px">
  <img class="img1" src="images/cake.jpg" width="350px" height="607px">
  <img class="img1" src="images/pizza.jpg" width="350px" height="607px">
</div>
```

As you can see in the navigation bar, the HOME button's font is different from the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying moving the text "Home" out of the `<i>` tag.

Before: `<i class="fa fa-home w3-xxlarge"> Home</i>`

After: `<i class="fa fa-home w3-xxlarge"></i> Home`